# Change quantity of self.variables in subclass based on user's demand

Tags: python, class, subclass, python-3.5

Can I change variables in a subclass object based on user need? If so, how, or is there a different approach?

I want a subclass list of variables to grow in size based on a user's demands without having to prewrite the *self.*variables in the **init**, and allow the user to make a list.

How do you handle a list with changing length in the subclass?

```
class MyClass(object): 
    def __init__(self, list1, list2): # list 1: keys; list 2: values

        len1 = len(list1) # Changing range based on desired keys
        for i in range(len1): 

             self.list1[i] = list2[i] # desired effect

List1 = ['first','second','third']; List2 = [1,2,3];
print(MyClass(List1,List2))
List1.append('fourth'); List2.append(4)
print(MyClass(List1,List2))
```

Desired output is `[[getattr(item, x) for x in list1] for item in list2]` returns 3 values for first instance and 4 values for second instance.

The error I receive when trying `getattr(item, x)` on an instance of this class is `AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute <key>`, where `<key>` is list1, rather than the value in list1.

The work-around I have is to pre-populate the fields, like so:

```
import re

kLs = ("the", "list", "of", "new", "caught", "values")

let = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
reAN = re.compile("\w+")
for k in kLs: print('self.'+reAN.search(re.sub(r"\s+", "", k)).group()+' = '+let[kLs.index(k)])
```

I have to do this each time I want to subtract or add a variable. This won't work. Anyone?

Comment: I've made a number of edits, but haven't received any response since Thursday. Is there any reason why? Can you at least remove your hold and allow other people to respond? No mention has been made of why this isn't an appropriate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Same as always:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
MyClass(*space)
```

Comment: I  didn't specify in the original post, but it is the amendment inside the subclass that I am looking to change, as much as get the variables in. Not sure if that's possible, however.